# Удаление объектов C#

Tags: c#

Подскажи пожалуйста,почему у меня не удаляются объекты в SellProduct.
Я первый раз покупаю себе к примеру 1 товар,потом второй второй раз нажимаю 1 и у меня список начинает дублироваться и получается каша

````
using System.Collections.Generic;


namespace Shop
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            bool isExit = false;

            Player player = new Player("Вася");
            Seller seller = new Seller();

            while (!isExit)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("1.Показать список товаров в магазине\n2.Купить товар\n3.Мои заказы");
                int menu = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                Console.WriteLine();
                switch (menu)
                {
                    case 1:
                        seller.SellersProducts();
                        Console.WriteLine();
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        seller.SellersProducts();
                        seller.SellProduct(player);
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        player.ShowProducts();
                        break;
                    default:
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    class Product
    {
        public int ID { get; private set; }
        public string Name { get; private set; }
        public int Count { get; private set; }

        public Product(int id, string name, int count)
        {
            ID = id;
            Name = name;
            Count = count;
        }

        public void ShowInfo()
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"ID товара - {ID}, наименование - {Name}, в количестве - {Count}");
        }
    }

    class Player
    {
        public List<Product> PlayerProducts = new List<Product>();

        private string _name;

        public Player(string name)
        {
            _name = name;
        }

        public void ShowProducts()
        {
            if (PlayerProducts.Count > 0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Ваши товары: ");
                foreach (var product in PlayerProducts)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"{product.Name} в количестве {product.Count}");
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Вы еще ничего не приобрели.");
            }
            Console.WriteLine();
        }

        public void AddProduct(Product id)
        {
            PlayerProducts.Add(id);
        }
    }

    class Seller
    {
        public List<Product> Products = new List<Product>();

        public void SellersProducts()
        {
            Products.Add(new Product(1, "Материнская плата", 1));
            Products.Add(new Product(2, "Процессор", 1));
            Products.Add(new Product(3, "Видеокарта", 1));
            Products.Add(new Product(4, "Оперативная память", 1));
            Products.Add(new Product(5, "Хард", 1));
            Products.Add(new Product(6, "Клавиатура", 1));
            Products.Add(new Product(7, "Мышка", 1));

            foreach (var product in Products.ToArray())
            {
                product.ShowInfo();
            }
        }

        public Product FindProduct(int id)
        {
            foreach (var product in Products)
            {
                if (product.ID == id)
                {
                    return product;
                }
            }
            return null;
        }

        public void SellProduct(Player player)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Введите ID товара,который хотите купить: ");
            int id = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            var findProduct = FindProduct(id);
            if (findProduct != null)
            {
                player.AddProduct(findProduct);
                Products.Remove(findProduct);
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Этот продукт уже продан!");
            }
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
    }
}```
````

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вы каждый раз вызываете `seller.SellersProducts()`, который добавляет продукты. Сделайте это один раз в конструкторе:

```
class Seller
{
    public List<Product> Products = new List<Product>();

    public Seller()
    {
        Products.Add(new Product(1, "Материнская плата", 1));
        Products.Add(new Product(2, "Процессор", 1));
        Products.Add(new Product(3, "Видеокарта", 1));
        Products.Add(new Product(4, "Оперативная память", 1));
        Products.Add(new Product(5, "Хард", 1));
        Products.Add(new Product(6, "Клавиатура", 1));
        Products.Add(new Product(7, "Мышка", 1));
    }

    public void SellersProducts()
    {
        foreach (var product in Products)
        {
            product.ShowInfo();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо!Помогло